# Disable Cisco Router syslog messages

Tags: cisco, syslog, terminal, debug

I am trying to disable syslog messages from showing in my cisco 1kv tty. The conundrum is terminal monitor has a single command to set the logging level `#logging terminal <severity>`, and if I choose anything above informational I will get all of the syslog messages showing in the tty output once I execute `#terminal monitor`.
Long story short: I want to have all of the debug messages showing on my terminal once I execute `#terminal monitor` without the brutal surge of syslog messages.
Severities:

```
  <0-7>          Logging severity level
  alerts         Immediate action needed           (severity=1)
  critical       Critical conditions               (severity=2)
  debugging      Debugging messages                (severity=7)
  discriminator  Establish MD-Console association
  emergencies    System is unusable                (severity=0)
  errors         Error conditions                  (severity=3)
  filtered       Enable filtered logging
  informational  Informational messages            (severity=6)
  notifications  Normal but significant conditions (severity=5)
  warnings       Warning conditions                (severity=4)
  xml            Enable logging in XML
  <cr>           <cr>
```

Thanks